# Mysql Union two tables with different values

Tags: mysql, select, union, no-duplicates

I need to return all the values from one table and then join this table to another query without duplicating values. This is my query so far.

```
    CREATE TABLE tmp_tbl (Id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY, Per VARCHAR(30), Des VARCHAR(50), Rol INT(11));
INSERT INTO tmp_tbl(Id, Per, Des, Rol)
SELECT DISTINCT
     p.p_id AS Id,
    p.p_title AS Per,
    p.p_description AS Des,
    '' AS Rol
    FROM perm p;

 SELECT  
    p.p_id AS Id,
    p.p_title AS Per,
    p.p_description AS Des,
    r.id AS Rol
    FROM perm p
    LEFT JOIN roles rp
        ON p.p_id = rp.p_id
    INNER JOIN rol r
        ON r.id = rp.r_id AND rp.r_id IN (101)
    UNION  ALL
SELECT * FROM
tmp_tbl;
 DROP TABLE tmp_tbl;
```

The statement returns all the rows from the first select but duplicates the rows on the union from the second select statement.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the

```
UNION  ALL
```

with

```
UNION
```

`union all` will not remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`.
Infact `UNION` removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), `UNION ALL` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION DISTINCT` to be sure :

```
(SELECT p.p_id AS Id, p.p_title AS Per, p.p_description AS Des, r.id AS Rol
FROM perm p
LEFT JOIN roles rp ON p.p_id = rp.p_id
INNER JOIN rol r ON r.id = rp.r_id AND rp.r_id IN (101))
UNION  DISTINCT
(SELECT * FROM tmp_tbl);
```